# Drupal 6 caching and blocks

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

I've read all over the place and I'm trying to figure out if I am understanding the way caching happens in Drupal 6. We have a site that has a real time stock ticker in it. We have Drupal caching enabled so the stock price ends up getting cached and frozen at a specific spot. I figured a way I could handle it would be to put the ticker in a block I make in a custom module and set BLOCK_NO_CACHE, but if I'm understanding this correctly, if you have site caching enabled, then the ENTIRE page gets cached including any and all blocks on it regardless of their individual cache settings. Is this correct? So am I unable to take advantage of site caching then if I have certain spots that should not cache? Does anyone know of another solution I might be able to use to have the best of both worlds? To be able to have site caching, but also have a real time stock ticker? By the way, the stock ticker is making a JSON request to the Yahoo finance API to get the quote.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if your ticker is sending requests to Yahoo this happens between the user's browser and the Yahoo API server. Drupal has nothing to cache in this case and your problem may be elsewhere...

Comment: Sorry pamatt, I wasn't clear. It's actually done via PHP using file_get_contents() in the page.tpl.php file, but you're right, if I moved this to maybe using jQuery and doing a .ajax call, this might not be affected by the caching. I will test that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the directive `BLOCK_NO_CACHE` is only applicable to block level. However when page caching is enabled then Drupal will cache the entire page (which includes the block as well). But this is only applicable to anonymous users. Drupal's philosophy is that the content for anonymous users is always the same so they get served the cached page. But this is not applicable to authenticated users. Since different users might have different access to certain parts of the page (e.g. the links block will look different for an admin than a regular user).

You might want to have a look at this discussion: [BLOCK_NO_CACHE not working for anonymous users](http://drupal.org/node/791142)

And there is a solution, which you'll stumble upon this discussion. It's this module: [Ajax Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks). Extract from the module description:

> Permits to load some blocks by additional AJAX request after loading
>   the whole cached page when the page is viewed by anonymous user. It is
>   suitable for sites which are mostly static, and the page caching for
>   anonymous users is a great benefit, but there are some pieces of
>   information that have to be dynamic.

Comment: Awesome that sounds perfect. THANKS!